# Join multilevel relationship in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

There are 3 tables: ParentCategories -> Categories -> Articles.

- ParentCategory(ID, Name)
- Category(ID, parentCategoryID, Name)
- Article(ID, caregoryID, Name)

How do I select all articles with specified `parentCategoryID` (the table articles has only reference to `categoreID`, not to `ParentCategoryID`) using LINQ to SQL?

Something like this:

```
articles = (
    from a in db.Articles
    join c in db.Categories
    on ????????????
    join pc in db.ParentCategories 
    on c.ParentCategoryId equals pc.ID
    ...);
```

Comment: If you prefer your own solution, you should post it as an answer (instead of an update) and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
articles = from a in db.Articles
          join c in db.Categories
          on myParentCategoryID equals c.ParentCategoryId
select a;
```

Answer (score 3):

(If I understand your schema correctly) you could use an **implicit join** strategy like:

```
var articles = db.Categories
    .Where(c => c.ParentCategoryID == yourParentCategoryID)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Articles)
    .ToList();
```

The implicit join requires that you have [Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629295.aspx) set up between your entities in your O/R designer.

Comment: No. The variable "c" (type - Category) doen't contain the definition for "Articles".

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you need to set up an association in your O/R designer between your entities.  If you create an association between `Category` and `Article`, that will create an `Articles` (or whatever you choose to name it) property on `Category`.